# How to pass value next screen using navigatorKey in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I'm using bloc state management.
and using `NavigatorState` to navigate screen but now need to pass value to next screen but here , dunno how to pass value to screen using `NavigatorState.

```
class AppView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppViewState createState() => _AppViewState();
}

class _AppViewState extends State<AppView> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  NavigatorState get _navigator => _navigatorKey.currentState;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: theme,
      navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return BlocListener<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
          listener: (context, state) {

            switch (state.status) {
              case AuthenticationStatus.authenticated:
                _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                  Home.route(),
                  (route) => false,
                );
                   

                  // Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> 
                  //    Home( currentUser:state.user)), (route) => false);
                
                 
              
                break;
              case AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated:
                _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                AuthPage.route(), //LoginPage
                  (route) => false,
                  
                );
                break;

                 case AuthenticationStatus.unknown:
                _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                  SplashPage.route(),
                  (route) => false,
                );
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
          },
          child: child,
        );
      },
      onGenerateRoute: (_) => SplashPage.route(),
    );
  }
}
```

Above commented code is not working , getting exception

```
Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by replacing
this:

```
 _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                  Home.route(),
                  (route) => false,
                );
```

With this:

```
  _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil( MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> 
                     Home( currentUser:state.user)), (route) => false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `_navigator.currentState.pushAndRemoveUntil`

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but  I have found the solution.